# How to add favicon (.ico) file for a site in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

We are using sitecore 9.0 and SXA 1.8.1

We want to add a favicon for our site.

There is an option available in the path `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings` to upload the favicon, but when I try to upload it by selecting the item from the media library, it says:

> The selected item does not contain an image.

The type of image I am trying to select has an extension `.ico`. 
Please let us know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add `ico` as a mediatype for Sitecore? You could add it with a patch like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaTypes>
        <mediaType name="icon" extensions="ico">
          <mimeType>image/x-icon</mimeType>
          <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
          <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/image</sharedTemplate>
          <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/image</versionedTemplate>
        </mediaType>
      </mediaTypes>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This should make Sitecore recognize ico files and solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked !!

Comment: Good one. Thank you for the patch.

Comment: This helped me as well.  Thanks!